# Is there any way to change the toLowerCase method to the substring method in the code hereunder?

Tags: list, dart

Is there any way to change the toLowerCase method to the substring method in the code hereunder?

Here is my non-optimal solution :

```
void main() {
  List<String> users = ['anna', 'viKtor', 'Mike', 'aleX', 'dan'];

  var lowers = users.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()).toList();

  final letters = lowers.map((item) => item[0].toUpperCase()).toList();
}
```

And here is a task:

There is an array of users. Create a new array from it so that the names start with a capital letter and the rest of the characters are in lower case. For example, Anna, Viktor, and so on.

```
List<String> users = ['anna', 'viKtor', 'Mike', 'aleX', 'dan'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  final users = ['anna', 'viKtor', 'Mike', 'aleX', 'dan'];

  final lowers = users.map((e) {
    final stringBuffer = StringBuffer();

    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        stringBuffer.write(e[i].toUpperCase());
      } else {
        stringBuffer.write(e[i].toLowerCase());
      }
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
  }).toList();

  print(lowers); // [Anna, Viktor, Mike, Alex, Dan]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume it's a simple case. Then you can just do:

```dart
String capitalizeWord(String word) => 
    characters[0].toUpperCase() + characters.substrin(1).toLowerCase();

// And use it as:
List<String> users = ['anna', 'viKtor', 'Mike', 'aleX', 'dan'];
var capitalizedUsers = [for (var user in users) capitalizeWord(user)];
```

This makes a number of assumptions:

- the characters only taking up one code unit,
- the input is a single word
- with no whitespace in front.

If you are sure that's always the case, you are done.

If not, you probably need to use the `characters` package to get to the *first* character.

```dart
import "package:characters/characters.dart";
String capitalizeWord(String word) =>
  word.characters.first.toUpperCase() + "${word.characters.skip(1)}".toLowerCase();
```

This will properly split multi-code-unit characters into the first character and the rest.